# How to launch the same activity even app is in background?

Tags: android

I have 3 activities in my application, log in, A and B. login activity is my launcher page. After login, it redirects to activity A.While click on home button now, it pause the activity A and goes to background and while click on application icon it relaunches the activity A. I need to launch the login activity even activity A is in the background. How can I achieve this, please help?

Comment: use sharedpreference

Comment: or any other data saving method (SQL/files/shared prefs)

Comment: simply make him logout when activity goes in background but what you are trying to achieve is not a good practice from usability perspective

Comment: In onStop() of Activity A, call finish() so it is not kept in the activity stack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to finish your every activity whenever your app goes into background

> HomeWatcher.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;

public class HomeWatcher {

    static final String TAG = HomeWatcher.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context mContext;
    private IntentFilter mFilter;
    private OnHomePressedListener mListener;
    private InnerRecevier mRecevier;

    public HomeWatcher(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    }

    public void setOnHomePressedListener(OnHomePressedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mRecevier = new InnerRecevier();
    }

    public void startWatch() {
        if (mRecevier != null) {
            mContext.registerReceiver(mRecevier, mFilter);
        }
    }

    public void stopWatch() {
        if (mRecevier != null) {
            mContext.unregisterReceiver(mRecevier);
        }
    }

    class InnerRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver {
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_GLOBAL_ACTIONS = "globalactions";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS = "recentapps";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {
                String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);
                if (reason != null) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY)) {
                            mListener.onHomePressed();
                        } else if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS)) {
                            mListener.onRecentAppPressed();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    private static MyApplication mInstance;
    public static String TAG = MyApplication.class.getSimpleName();
    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);

        HomeWatcher mHomeWatcher = new HomeWatcher(this);
        mHomeWatcher.setOnHomePressedListener(new OnHomePressedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHomePressed() {
                // do other stuff before finish
                Log.d(TAG, "onHomePressed");
                if (mActivity != null)
                    mActivity.finishAffinity();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRecentAppPressed() {
                // do other stuff before finish
                Log.d(TAG, "onRecentAppPressed ");
                if (mActivity != null)
                    mActivity.finishAffinity();
            }
        });
        mHomeWatcher.startWatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

    }
}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:name="your_package_name.MyApplication">
    ....
 </application>
```

Comment: I tried this code snippet but onRecentAppPressed() is called twice on a single click of button. Any solution?

Comment: Can you share, how you have implemented?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to launch login activity when "A" activity comes from background, you could use the "onResume" method. You could launch login activity with a normal intent and in the same login activity you should check if the user is logged or not to act accordingly